# EAGLE CAD Connecting fills to components and leave traces bare

Tags: pcb, design, eaglecad

So I have actually have two different questions, I am making a custom board for one of my projects and I can not seem to get the result I want using eagle cad.

This is what I have in eagle

[image]

Its a small board with 3 SMD components on each side (front and back sides mirror each other) and I drew out copper pours for the busses (High amperage I plan to flow solder to make a beefy connection)

However when I upload it to Oshpark I get this

[image]

As you can see it comes up with gaps between the fill and the SMD Pads, Not sure how to fix this Ive done some research with little success.

THe other problem I am having is that I would like to have the copper pours bare but when I upload them I get this:

[image]

And I can not figure out how to take off the coating on top of the fill.

Here is a link to my BRD file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6GY9aA5YJi8bU9pZUtnR3BvRHc

Thanks in advance,
Jaret

Answer (score 1):

A copper pour looks like this for example: -

[image]

Notice how it skirts around component pads/traces that it is not meant to connect to but connects (via thermals), to the pads it is intended to connect to. My point is this - have you properly set the net name of the pour (or fill if in fact you mean a copper fill) to that net it should connect to.

For the solder mask, you have to create keep-out areas that follow the shape of the pour (or fill) to have exposed copper.

Comment: Okay, So I have the thermals but it seems like if I have multiple thermals and rename them different things they all still connect on the board layout. Is there a way to isolate them by name?

Comment: I neither see thermals in your picture nor understand your question. Thermals are automatically generated and they don't have an editable net name.

Comment: Alright so how do I see what the names of the thermals are, Sorry I am fairly new to eagle cad and spent about 6 hours trying to figure out how to do this last night and got nowhere.

Comment: If it helps I had to make the smd part myself because I could not find the proper package to download online.